# C# sort a dictionary against a string list?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following list (ignore the LST ==> part):

```
LST ==>Username
LST ==>Password
LST ==>SampleRequestValue
LST ==>SampleComplexRequest
LST ==>SampleComplexRequest.SampleTestBValue
LST ==>SampleComplexRequest.SampleTestAValue
```

and the following Key List from a dictionary (ignore the DICT ==> part):

```
DICT ==>Password
DICT ==>Username
DICT ==>SampleRequestValue
DICT ==>SampleComplexRequest.SampleTestAValue
DICT ==>SampleComplexRequest.SampleTestBValue
```

I want the dictionary sorted in the order of the list (i.e. Username before Password).

Saw a few samples on SO of sorta / kinda / not really examples for this... but not really a similar scenario. Also want it to be as fast as possible rather then brute forcing it.

LST may have more items then DICT. I only care about sorting DICT. DICT will always have a matching entry in LST. I just want the DICT by LST order.

Comment: `Also want it to be as fast as possible rather then brute forcing it.`  How many elements are we talking about here?  It's going to be O(n) no matter what you do (you have to touch every element).

Comment: Why won't they have the same number of items, and where should the items without matches go in the sort order?

Comment: And how do you propose to deal with the elements in the dictionary that are not in the list?

Comment: If you want us to ignore the DICT==> and LST ==> then why include them in your question? You should make your question as clean as possible and remove extraneous stuff we don't need to see.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Shouldn't be that many.

Comment: So you've got a few milliseconds then, right?

Comment: What does it mean to sort a dictionary? Are you looking for a list of key/value pairs in the output? just the values? (no longer a dictionary)

Comment: @DerrickMoeller LST *may* have more items. I can't think of a scenario right now where DICT will have more. DICT will always have a match in LST.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yeah... I just didn't want a super slow brute force way. Was hoping there was some kind of trick I could do...

Comment: @Mr.Mindor to get the order of the dictionary in the order of the list... its actually an ordered dictionary.

Comment: OK, so basically you want a new ordered dictionary that conforms to the order imposed by the list, right?

Comment: That information (actually OrderedDictionary) should be in the question itself.

Comment: If LST always stays the same (or doesn't change much) then it'll be more efficient to create another dictionary that has the LST items as key and their index in LST as value so you can access their index in LST in constant time (instead of having to loop through LST to find their index)

Comment: @Knoop I got it to work with Roberts approach which went the other way. Loop through LST and TryGetValue on the DICT. Although he deleted his answer. I don't control the original creation of DICT. That's coming from a 3rd party library. I just need to fix the sort order.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs **and expected results for those sample inputs**. _In other words, make the question clear **in the question** not in the comments._

Comment: Just saw the comment that you don't have control over the original dictionary, so I updated my answer at the bottom to show how you can just pass in the original dictionary to the constructor, and the sorting will happen automatically.

Comment: What result do you want? How do you want to use it? Do you want to enumerate the `OrderedDictionary` in the new order? A `Dictionary` is normally used unorderd, so...

Comment: @SledgeHammer `OrderedDictionary` doesn't seem to have a TryGetValue method. (this might be why Robert deleted his answer, it was posted just at the same time as your comment that it was an ordered dictionary, and if you were using `OrderedDictionary` his solution wouldn't work)  What is the actual class you are working with? I realize you already have a solution from Robert's answer, but As mjwills and Rufus have requested, correct sample code would greatly improve this question and make it so that people could write correct answers.

Comment: `OrderedDictionary` doesn't _need_ a `TryGetValue` - just use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.item?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Specialized_OrderedDictionary_Item_System_Object_ and check whether the result was `null`. And yes, a [mcve] would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to write a small custom comparer class that uses a list to determine comparison values:

```
public class ListComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public List<string> ComparisonList { get; set; }

    public ListComparer(List<string> comparisonList)
    {
        ComparisonList = comparisonList;
    }

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (ComparisonList == null || !ComparisonList.Contains(x))
            return 1;

        if (ComparisonList.Contains(y))
            return ComparisonList.IndexOf(x).CompareTo(ComparisonList.IndexOf(y));

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Then you can pass this to the constructor of a [SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.1), which will then use it each time an item is added to the dictionary. This way you don't have to call `OrderBy` on the dictionary every time new values are added (which also has the negative side-effect of creating a whole new dictionary each time).

Here's a code sample that may help. Notice that we add "Password" first, then "Username", but when we output the items, they are in the expected order:

```
static void Main()
{
    var comparisonList = new List<string>
    {
        "Username",
        "Password",
        "SampleRequestValue",
        "SampleComplexRequest",
        "SampleComplexRequest.SampleTestBValue",
        "SampleComplexRequest.SampleTestAValue",
    };

    // Add items in an "unorderd" order
    var items = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(new ListComparer(comparisonList))
    {
        {"Password", "LetMeIn"},
        {"Username", "JohnDoe"}
    };

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} = {item.Value}");
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

---

I just saw that you don't have control over the initial dictionary, but are willing to create a new one. In that case, you can simply use the overload constructor that takes in a dictionary and a comparer, and it will be automatically sorted on your list:

```
 var sortedItems = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(
     originalDictionary, new ListComparer(comparisonList));
```

Comment: as Knoop says in a comment on the question, transforming the list into a dictionary of <LST entry, index> can result in a significant performance improvement over repeated calls to IndexOf particularly if you have more than a few entries in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ this is pretty easy.

First, setup a `Dictionary<string,int>` to represent your desired sort order:

```
var orderList = new[] { "Username", "Password", "SampleRequestValue", "SampleComplexRequest", "SampleComplexRequest.SampleTestBValue", "SampleComplexRequest.SampleTestAValue" }
                .ToList();

var sortOrder = orderList
                    .Select((s, p) => new { s, p })
                    .ToDictionary(sp => sp.s, sp => sp.p);
```

Then you can sort the `DictionaryEntry`s from the `OrderedDictionary`:

```
var ans = src.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().OrderBy(de => sortOrder[(string)de.Key]);
```

If you want the answer an an `OrderedDictionary`, you can convert back using an extension method:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static OrderedDictionary ToOrderedDictionary<TKey,TValue,TObj>(this IEnumerable<TObj> src, Func<TObj,TKey> keyFn, Func<TObj, TValue> valueFn) {
        var ans = new OrderedDictionary();
        foreach (var s in src)
            ans.Add(keyFn(s), valueFn(s));
        return ans;
    }    
}
```

Now just use the extension method:

```
var odans = ans.ToOrderedDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value);
```

Comment: very similar to the answer I started writing, but from comments by the OP it still isn't clear they are actually using `OrderedDictionary` or some other dictionary that can be described as having an order. (like `SortedDictionary`)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `OrderBy` method :

```
var SortedDic = dic.OrderBy(o => lst.IndexOf(o.Key));
```

Comment: Make sure to include `using System.Linq`.

Comment: @BJ Myers already doing so. If I use a regular `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` there is an OrderBy extension available, but the result is no longer a dictionary...

Comment: Whoops, I was thinking of SortedDictionary.  OrderedDictionary isn't generic, so LINQ doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't the List.IndexOf O(n)?

Comment: You can put in `Cast<DictionaryEntry>()` to make it work, but `IndexOf` isn't terribly efficient.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor you can't have a 'Dictionary' and use it sorted, for that u must use a 'SortedDictionary'  .. he wanted to iterate it by order of the list.

Comment: In comments on the OP he indicated he was using an "ordered dictionary". He also indicated he wanted a new dictionary in the order of the list. `OrderedDictionary` is a distinct class from the generic `SortedDictionary` both of which can be accessed by index as well as key. In this sense both are _ordered_ and can be iterated in the order of the list if properly constructed. If he is using `OrderedDictionary` then your solution won't even compile. If he is using a different type of dictionary, your solution still doesn't give a dictionary in the order of the list but an `IOrderedCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Here are three extension methods that will do what you want in different ways.

They are used like this (`KeySortItems` and `ValueSortItems` are different `List<string>` lists:

```
DictionaryItems.ListOrderByKey(KeySortItems)
DictionaryItems.ListOrderByValue(ValueSortItems)
DictionaryItems.ListOrderBy(KeySortItems, (kv, value) => kv.Key.Equals(value))

public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> ListOrderByKey<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, List<TValue> list)
{
    foreach (var value in list)
        foreach (var kv in dictionary)
            if (kv.Key.Equals(value))
            {
                yield return kv;
                break;
            }
}

public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> ListOrderByValue<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, List<TValue> list)
{
    foreach (var value in list)
        foreach (var kv in dictionary)
            if (kv.Value.Equals(value))
                yield return kv;
}

public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> ListOrderBy<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, List<TValue> list, Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>, TValue, bool> func)
{
    foreach (var value in list)
        foreach (var kv in dictionary)
            if (func.Invoke(kv, value))
                yield return kv;
}
```

---

#### Copy and paste console app.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static List<string> KeySortItems { get; set; } = new List<string>()
    {
        "Username",
        "Password",
        "Item not in Dictionary",
        "SampleRequestValue",
        "SampleComplexRequest"
    };

    public static List<string> ValueSortItems { get; set; } = new List<string>()
    {
        "Mathew",
        "1234",
        "Item not in Dictionary",
        "Sample Request",
        "Something Complex"
    };

    public static Dictionary<string, string> DictionaryItems { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        ["Password"] = "1234",
        ["Username"] = "Mathew",
        ["SampleComplexRequest"] = "Something Complex",
        ["SampleRequestValue"] = "Sample Request"
    };


    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Original Dictionary");
        foreach (var kv in DictionaryItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key} : { kv.Value}");
        }


        Console.WriteLine("\nSorted by Key");
        foreach (var kv in DictionaryItems.ListOrderByKey(KeySortItems))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key} : { kv.Value}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nSorted by Value");
        foreach (var kv in DictionaryItems.ListOrderByValue(ValueSortItems))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key} : { kv.Value}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nSorted by Keys via func");
        foreach (var kv in DictionaryItems.ListOrderBy(KeySortItems, (kv, value) => kv.Key.Equals(value)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key} : { kv.Value}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> ListOrderByKey<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, List<TValue> list)
    {
        foreach (var value in list)
            foreach (var kv in dictionary)
                if (kv.Key.Equals(value))
                    yield return kv;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> ListOrderByValue<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, List<TValue> list)
    {
        foreach (var value in list)
            foreach (var kv in dictionary)
                if (kv.Value.Equals(value))
                    yield return kv;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> ListOrderBy<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, List<TValue> list, Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>, TValue, bool> func)
    {
        foreach (var value in list)
            foreach (var kv in dictionary)
                if (func.Invoke(kv, value))
                    yield return kv;
    }
}

//OUTPUT
//Original Dictionary
//Password : 1234
//Username : Mathew
//SampleComplexRequest : Something Complex
//SampleRequestValue : Sample Request

//Sorted by Key
//Username : Mathew
//Password : 1234
//SampleRequestValue : Sample Request
//SampleComplexRequest : Something Complex

//Sorted by Value
//Username : Mathew
//Password : 1234
//SampleRequestValue : Sample Request
//SampleComplexRequest : Something Complex

//Sorted by Keys via func
//Username : Mathew
//Password : 1234
//SampleRequestValue : Sample Request
//SampleComplexRequest : Something Complex
```